# How to fetch songs by genre/category with the Apple Music API

Tags: ios, apple-music

I have spent some time on the Apple Music API docs on how to list songs by genre but can't find it. How can I use the API to list songs that belong to a genre e.g rock? The search endpoint is close but I can't limit it to a genre. Thanks in advance.
Apple Music API